# clock_gettime error logging into VSFTP on Amazon Linux 2 from certain clients only

Tags: vsftpd

We have an FTP server VSFTPD running on AWS Linux 2; users are chrooted. Some users can log on fine, others are getting connection failed in WinSCP and an error in Filezilla. On investigation, the error is:

Relink `/lib64/libnss_myhostname.so.2` with `/lib64/librt.so.1` for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime`

Oddly, the exact same configuration which works for some clients fails for the others.

This doesn't seems to be a common error and I would value ideas about how to fix it, either in the VSFTPD configuration or the clients.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think the error is misleading and the real problem is with the firewall on the networks used by the clients that can't connect. Maybe the error comes when VSFTPD is trying to create an error message? Anyway we have found a fix by using FTP over TLS which is also more secure.